# WordPress on Google App Engine Standard Environment: impossible to upload cron.yaml

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, cron

I have just installed a fresh copy of WordPress on a Google Cloud Platform App Engine STANDARD environment following these steps: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard

I have some problem with the `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`

I have reviewd many times cron.yaml file, overwritten, and now is pretty empy (`cron:`)

I'm always getting this error:

```
xxx@xxx:~/wordpress$ gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
Configurations to update:

descriptor:      [/home/xxx/wordpress/cron.yaml]
type:            [cron jobs]
target project:  [xxx-news]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Updating config [cron]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Comment: I used the same tutorial and I was able to deploy the cron.yaml. Could you share your cron.yaml here and check if there is anything wrong?

Comment: I have override some times my cron, deleted and recreated but there is not way to update the cron files

Comment: Please provide the cron.yaml to inspect it. Thanks

Comment: Link you have shared worked perfect for me but for 2 points: I skipped Step 2. under Setup as it was not necessary AND Instead of `php vendor/bin/wp-gae create` under Create a new WordPress project, I used `vendor\bin\wp-gae create`

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but are you using MS Visual Studio to edit your code?  I forget exactly what it is called, but by default, VS adds some weird two-byte unicode header to all files that it creates.  This header is not visible in some text editors so you might not know that it is there.  You also can't delete it in text editors that don't show it.

Try creating a new cron.yaml from scratch using emacs or some other text editor.

Comment: No i'm using nano terminal :D